# Pigeonhole Principle ( 65 particles, 2x2x2 box, distance between 2 no greater than 1.7)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

**Question:**
Imagine a small box with 2x2x2 dimensions which contains 65 particles floating around. Show that at any point, there are at least 9 particles with a distance no larger than 1.7 between any 2 of them.

**My attempt:**
I understand I must divide the box into 64 even sectors and place a particle in each.
Using the pigeonhole principle,

pigeons: particles

pigeonholes: sectors

I am just struggling to prove that there are 9 particles (with distance between any two) no greater than 1.7 apart.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $1.7 < \sqrt 3$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you take $8$ unit cubes within the cube of dimension $2 \times 2 \times 2$ and take $8$ groups of $8$ particles, the maximum distance that you can maintain between each of those groups is $\sqrt6$ and no two subgroups of those $8$ particles can be farther than $\sqrt3$ from each another without violating distance of $\sqrt3$ with another group. Now the $65$th particle will be at maximum distance of $\sqrt3$ at least from one of the groups. You still need to fill in the gaps with your working.

Comment: I made some changes to it. Please check.

Comment: okay, that's great! So because the distance is 1.7 this means that there is only one particle that exceeds the distance?

Comment: Also, if the distance was slightly over square root 3 would that prove there are 9 particles exceeding it?

Comment: $\sqrt3 \approx 1.73$ is the diagonal of the unit cube (the question should have said $\sqrt3$). So we definitely have at least $9$ particles that are within $\sqrt3$ of each another. You cannot place $64$ particles without $8$ of them being within $\sqrt3$ of each another and $65$th particle will be in one of those groups (within $\sqrt3$ distance of them). But you need to complete the reasoning and working.